# Run app from a service using CreateProcessAsUser

Tags: windows-vista, process, isolation-level, createprocessasuser, windows-services

I'm still trying to run an app calling it from windows service. I tried to use the way [described by Scott Allen](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2004/10/28/createprocessasuser.aspx). It works. But still I can't bring the app to the screen to interact with it. Help me pls.

Even if I'm telling it to run the service using my credentials it doesn't bring the app on my desktop. tell me please how to get the current logged user's desktop token and run the app on that desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop to something like "winsta0\default" ?

Comment: @plotnick may you could post some example code and/or tell us about any error messages etc